# how to send protobuf as part of XML

Tags: android, xml, protocol-buffers

i have create a `protobuf` sample code in android as follows

```
Person john =
  Person.newBuilder()
    .setId(1234)
    .setName("John Doe")
    .setEmail("jdoe@example.com")
    .addPhone(
      Person.PhoneNumber.newBuilder()
        .setNumber("555-4321")
        .setType(Person.PhoneType.HOME))
    .build();
```

now i want to send this `john` object as a part of `xml` building block over network

so far i have seen following methods so that i can send `bytes` over network

```
john.toByteArray() and john.toByteString()
```

but i think when i will embed into xml tag as follows it will be the string representation only and from that i can not get the data back

```
"<data>" + john.toByteArray() + "</data>"
```

so how can i pass the `protobuf` message with `XML` ?

***note:** i don't want to use the `base64` encoding as it will eventually increasing the size of a block*

Comment: I wanted to suggest base64, but saw your note. What is the problem with it?

Comment: its too large as compared to protobuf , so data payload is big in that case

Comment: Base64 + gzip should reduce size, if memory serves?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here is that protobuf encoding is binary while XML is text.  You can't embed binary data directly into text; you need to encode it as text somehow.

Unfortunately, there is simply no way to do that without increasing the data size.  If size is your concern, base64 is likely your best option -- this is exactly what it was designed to do.

Another possibility would be to encode the message in protobuf text format using `.toString()` and then parse it using `com.google.protobuf.TextFormat`.  This will produce a human-readable encoding, but it will be much larger than the binary encoding.

Yet another option would be to write a custom translator which uses the protobuf reflection iterfaces (e.g. `com.google.protobuf.Message#getField()`) to read individual fields and convert them to nested XML elements.  However, this is complicated and will probably end up taking even more space than protobuf text format.

Comment: so do you have any idea what methods are being used by the messengers like `WhatsApp` to send file efficiently ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what protocol `WhatsApp` uses.

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that compressed base64 should be similar in size to compressing the original binary data, because a good compressor will recognize that only a subset of the character set is being used.  So if you compress your XML then base64 shouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

These are the options that I'm aware of:

using this [3rd party library](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/).

*With this method, you can generate xml that you can embed in your outer xml*

using the [TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat) API, though parsing seem to be possible only [in c](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format?csw=1#TextFormat.Parser).

from protobuf to string format:

```
TextFormat.shortDebugString((myProtobufMessage);
```

from string format to protobufm in c++ code

```
TextFormat:parseFromString(dataString, &myProtobufMessage);
```

(I didn't try this myself, but I saw [this reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/qoJnk9aFa1k)).

*With this method you generate a String that you can embed in your XML, and on the receiving end, take that String and convert it to protobuf Message objects.*

using protobuf > binary > base64 - **instead** of xml altogether. 
You can probably send all the data in the wrapping XML inside the protobuf message. This is what I do.

*With this method you can forget about XML and use protobuf for everything. This is the original purpose of protobuf, and this is what it is best for.*

Comment: so you mean  , you initial wrap all the data in protobuf then send that buffer using xml am i correct ?